# How to set content-security-policy header?

Tags: http-headers, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

The website `https://www.example.com` with header `content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'self';` is unable to open with `<iframe>`

This website contain a shareable url like `https://www.example.com/#/shareablelink` which should be allowed to open in `<iframe>` but as header  `content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'self';` also applied to this page, it is not working as expected.

Is there any way do so?

Its frontend is build on angular 5+

Comment: Can you provide some sample code showing what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP headers publish on the backend (server), so only the site owner can change those.

Link (https://www.example.com/#/shareablelink) with hash **#** works tricky:

- part before **#** is served by server - be sends to server on click and will get reply from server (if you do not handle onClick by script in browser)
- part after **#** is served locally in browser (by script or by built-in browser navigation) and never be sent to server

Therefore CSP HTTP header on the page `https://www.example.com/#/shareablelink` always will be the same as on `https://www.example.com/`. The part `#/shareablelink` normally is a scroll to '/shareablelink' anchor, or could be handled by javascript for any purposes (even send XMLHttpRequest to server, get response and change the page's content but not the HTTP header)